# Calling different parent-class methods with one decorator

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

So basically my problem seems like this.

```
class A():
    def func(self):
        return 3

class B():
    def func(self):
        return 4

class AA(A):
    def func(self):
        return super(AA, self).func

class BB(B):
    def func(self):
        return super(BB, self).func
```

The `func` function is doing some work and one of the things it does is getting some attribute(or running method or whatever) from it's parent class.

Since `func` originally does the same logic at both cases (except that only parent class changes) I'd like to do this with decorators.

Is it possible? if so how to do it? Do I have somehow to pass parent-class as a argument?

I'll be very grateful for answers it's been bothering me for a while now.

Comment: There are four different `func()` methods defined in your question, so when you refer it you need to be specific. Saying things like "Since func originally does..." is kind of meaningless otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `super` to access data attributes of a parent class.

Neither does a class need a parent in order for access to data attributes to work.

You can use a mixin to do the job:

```
# A and B stay the same - they still have a c attribute
class A():
    c = 3

class B():
    c = 4  # I've changed B to make it clear below

#Instead have a mixin which defines func()
class Mixin:
    def func(self):
        # func has its behaviour here
        return self.c

class AA(Mixin, A):
    pass
class BB(Mixin, B):
    pass

a = AA()
b = BB()
print(a.func())
print(b.func())
```

Output:

```
3
4
```

Comment: The problem is when the base class method name is the same name like in the parent class. And this is the case I have. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: In python3 you can just use super().func()

Comment: Would you be that kind and show how to do it in example that we're discusing?
I tried doing decorator but calling super().func() in it gives: __class__ cell not found runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a single class decorator by defining a generic method inside of it that does what you want, and then adding it to the class being decorated. Here's what I mean:

```
def my_decorator(cls):
    def call_super_func(self):
        return super(type(self), self).func()

    setattr(cls, 'call_super_func', call_super_func)
    return cls

class A():
    def func(self):
        print('in A.func')
        return 3

class B():
    def func(self):
        print('in B.func')
        return 4

@my_decorator
class AA(A):
    def func(self):
        print('in AA.func')
        return self.call_super_func()

@my_decorator
class BB(B):
    def func(self):
        print('in BB.func')
        return self.call_super_func()


aa = AA()
aa.func()
bb = BB()
bb.func()
```

Output:

```
in AA.func
in A.func
in BB.func
in B.func
```

Of course you could eliminate the need to do this by just defining baseclass for `A` and `B` that has a `call_super_func()` method in it that they would then both inherit.